# Example for converges series in the metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-groups

> Give example for converges series in the metric space:
>
> $$ \quad\quad\quad(\mathrm {R}^n,d_{\infty}),d_\infty=\max\mid x_i-y_i\mid$$

**My attempt:**

Let $\{X_n\}=x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\quad\quad\text{points  series}\\
\{Y_n\}=y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n$

converges if : $\lim
\limits_{n\to \infty}(X_n,Y_n)=(x_0,y_0)\quad\quad$

Let's take

$$\left(\frac 1 n+2, \frac{1}{n^2}+3\right) \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{}(2,3)$$

I am not sure at all that my attempt is correct, how can I find example?

sorry about my  english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your point isn't in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you use;

$$(x_n)_{n \geq 1} = \left(2+\frac{1}{n}, 3+ \frac{1}{n},...,0\right)$$

Then with the $d_{\infty}$ norm you have;

$$\left|\left(2+\frac{1}{n}, 3+ \frac{1}{n},...,0\right)\right| = 3$$

Therefore; $(x_n)  \to 3$.

Comment: why $(x_n)\to 3$?

Comment: The max difference between any of the coordinates is $3+ \frac{1}{n} - 0$ which goes to $3$ as $n \to \infty$.